# Problem with Adding multiple child objects to an existing entity in EF

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, ado.net

I need to add multiple child objects to an existing parent Object. I am instantiating my parent object and sets it Key/Id in my UI processing layer(to which my child objects will be added).

```
    Parent parenttoModify = new Parent();
    parenttoModify.Parent_Id = 5; //this comes from some Index of a dropdown or a key column of a grid, i Have put a dummy value here for example
    parenttoModify.Children.Add(child);
    parenttoModify.Children.Add(child2);
    DataAccess.ModifyParent(parenttoModify);
```

In my data access layer I have a method like :

```
public static bool ModifyParent(Parent parent)
        {
            int recordsAffected=0;
            using (TestEntities testContext = new TestEntities())
            {

                testContext.Parents.Attach(parent);
                var parentEntry = testContext.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(parent);
                parentEntry.ChangeState(System.Data.EntityState.Modified);
                recordsAffected =  testContext.SaveChanges();
            }
            return recordsAffected > 0 ? true : false;

        }
```

I get an error when testContext.Parent.Attach(parent) is called. It says:

> Object with same key already exist.

I am not sure why is this happening since i am not adding a parent object, I am just attaching it and adding child objects within it.

Any idea where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where do you add childs? I guess you are not showing all code. When you call `Attach` or `AddObject` EF always attaches or adds all entities from object graph which are not known (tracked) to context at the moment. The exception says that some entity - probably parent - is already tracked by the context. So you have either:

- Used shared context (you are creating a new instance in `ModifyParent` so it should not be a case)
- Load parent from the context first in `ModifyParent`
- Called `Attach` or `AddObject` on any child before attaching parent.

All these operations lead to the exception you are receiving.

Comment: I am creating instances of my child objects in my UI processing layer , so in this case child and Child2 are created before adding them to the parent objects

Comment: Exception occurs when I add multiple child(thats the problem I highlighted in my question as well). If I just add one child object, program successfully executes. I have one to many relationship between Parent table and a child table in the database

Comment: @Kunal: You must add `child` and `child2` to `parenttoModify.Children` **after** you have attached the parent to the context. Otherwise the whole object graph - parent plus children - will be attached to the context as Ladislav explained. It means that `child` and `child2` will not be in `Added` state but in state `Unchanged`, so EF considers them as existing objects with a valid entity key. Because you have created the child objects from scratch their key will be probably `0` (or whatever your default is). So, EF assumes there are two existing child entities with the same key `0`->exception!

Comment: @Slauma: + One for your explanation but thats bad from the design point of view, it implies that I need to send a seperate list of child objects from my UI processing layer. Is there a way to send only parents objects and child attached within them rather than sending a seperate list of child objects

Comment: @Kunal: You could try to loop through the `Children` collection and **add** each child object to the context **before** you attach the parent. Note, that the child objects must *not* have a reference set to the parent, otherwise EF would add the parent to the context too. You would probably get a new parent for every single child in the database. Not sure if this would work though.